# How To Implement Tap a UITableViewCell In a Section Navigating To Multiple UITableViewCells For Details?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm now learning UITableView class on iOS development,I want to implement Tap a UITableViewCell In a Section Navigating To Multiple UITableViewCells that accessory type for checkmark,What should i do?Please tell me how to do for details,Big Thanks for your help!

```
    Like this picture:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kowdl.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current view controller, you should implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you will need to create another `UITableViewController`, and when a cell is selected in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you will push your new `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `UITableView` delegate method- 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Now to identify specific `UITableViewCell` you can use `indexPath` - `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section`.